# Huge performance differences if I dont await in the Parent method C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I see there's a huge performance differences between using and NOT using `await` from the caller. I feel only the difference should be on the return. ie, If I use `await` then the caller method should wait for the response from called method before returning to the next statement else caller method doesn't need to wait for the response and it can continue to execute the further statements.

Here in my case There's a huge performance difference if use and don't use `await` in the caller method. ie, If I don't use `await` then it continues to execute the next statement in the caller without waiting but it's very much faster than using `await` in the caller.

Also, Am I using async & await correctly??

**Code**

```
        List<UserViewModel> _ListUser = new List<UserViewModel>();
    public XmlElement CreateUpdateUser(Stream input)
    {
        Main(_ListUser, HttpContext.Current); // using await here makes performance slower and without await it's faster but it returns to the next statement immediately thats the problem.
        return FormatResponse("S", "Record(s) created successfully.");
    }
    public async Task Main(List<UserViewModel> _ListUser, HttpContext current)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteToLog("Import Users - Start", 0, DateTime.Now);
            UserViewModel _objSiteFileUserSettings = await FillupSiteFileSettings(new UserViewModel());
            List<Branch> _branchCollection = await db.Branches.ToListAsync();
            List<UserType> _usertypeCollection = await db.UserTypes.ToListAsync();
            List<UserStatu> _userstatusCollection = await db.UserStatus.ToListAsync();
            List<UserDept> _userdeptCollection = await db.UserDepts.ToListAsync();
            List<UserLocation> _userlocationCollection = await db.UserLocations.ToListAsync();
            HttpContext.Current = current;
            //var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var x in _ListUser)
                Update1Record(x, _objSiteFileUserSettings, _branchCollection, _usertypeCollection, _userstatusCollection, _userdeptCollection, _userlocationCollection);
            WriteToLog("Import Users - End", 0, DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    public string Update1Record(UserViewModel objUser, UserViewModel _objSiteFileUserSettings, List<Branch> _Lbranch, List<UserType> _Lusertype, List<UserStatu> _Luserstatus, List<UserDept> _Luserdept, List<UserLocation> _Luserlocation)
    {
        objUser.BranchSiteFile = _objSiteFileUserSettings.BranchSiteFile;
        objUser.UsrTypeSiteFile = _objSiteFileUserSettings.UsrTypeSiteFile;
        objUser.UsrStatSiteFile = _objSiteFileUserSettings.UsrStatSiteFile;
        objUser.BranchId = objUser.Branch != null ? CheckBranch(objUser.Branch, _Lbranch) : null;
        objUser.UserDeptId = objUser.UserDept != null ? CheckDept(objUser.UserDept, _Luserdept) : null;
        objUser.UserLocationId = objUser.UserLocation != null ? CheckLocation(objUser.UserLocation, _Luserlocation) : null;
        objUser.UserStatusId = objUser.UserStatus != null ? CheckStatus(objUser.UserStatus, _Luserstatus) : null;
        objUser.UserTypeId = objUser.UserType != null ? CheckType(objUser.UserType, _Lusertype) : 0;
        objUser._iEmail = _objSiteFileUserSettings._iEmail;
        objUser._iSMS = _objSiteFileUserSettings._iSMS;

        using (var VibrantDbContext = new VIBRANT())
        using (var AuditDb = new VibrantAuditEntities())
        using (var VibrantTransaction = VibrantDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        using (var AuditTransaction = AuditDb.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            try
            {
                VibrantDbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                objUser.RecordTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                var _ObjUserItem = FillupDateTimeValues(objUser);
                ImportToDB(_ObjUserItem, 0, VibrantDbContext, AuditDb);
                BuildImportLog(objUser, VibrantDbContext, AuditDb);
                VibrantDbContext.SaveChanges();
                AuditDb.SaveChanges();
                VibrantTransaction.Commit();
                AuditTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                VibrantTransaction.Rollback();
                AuditTransaction.Rollback();
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return "S";
    }
    public XmlElement FormatResponse(string Status, string Message)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode response = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Response");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(response);
        XmlNode statusNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Status");
        statusNode.InnerText = Status;
        response.AppendChild(statusNode);
        XmlNode MessageNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Message");
        MessageNode.InnerText = Message;
        response.AppendChild(MessageNode);
        return xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand how Async works, you also say, await will cause thread wait for result come back from method, of course it will be slow, because if you not use await, Thread will continue process and no need to wait async method complete, for your code, if you not wait Main function, how do u know "Record Process Success"?

Comment: Side note: `throw new Exception(ex.ToString());` is horrible. You lose a lot of information that way. Replace it with `throw;`

Comment: @beibeizhu, The thing is `using await here makes performance slower and without await it's faster but it returns to the next statement immediately.`

Comment: Basically what you're asking is this: I phoned the local fastfood restaurant and ordered some food. It took me 30 minutes to wait for the food to be done, and to pick it up. Compare this to: I phoned the local fastfood restaurant and ordered some food. Then I said "The food is now on the table", total time it took was about 1 minute? Did I do it correctly? The answer is no.

Comment: @DonMax : Just like Lasse say, u need to wait for food done.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what i meant was using `await` it took about 2 mins but without `await` it took about `15` seconds to process 500 records. `Assume food preparation is the process of inserting 500 records.` I am trying to find why there's a time difference.

Comment: There is no huge difference in the performance, the performance is imperceptibly the same, however you are choosing not wait for it to complete. At about this point you probably should start reading up on the async and await pattern as you are confused about what it does

Answer (score 0):

No, I'd say you don't have a grasp yet on what async/await are, and when to use them. You should read up on await/async, and Task to fully understand the implementation, and most importantly the reason for using this structure. The common misconception about asynchronous code is that it makes code faster. This is often not accurate. It actually makes that specifc code a little slower, *however* it makes code more responsive, and allows you easily leverage the processing capability of your server.

In the simplest sense, code you write or call often has to wait for something. This could be for I/O such as disk access, database, or other communication. It can also have to wait for computation, code to finish working through something that will take a chunk of time to complete. If you have several of these tasks, that take on average say, 5 seconds each, and fire them off synchronously, the first task will finish after 5 seconds, the second after 10 seconds, and the third after 15 seconds.

For instance:

```
var result1 = DoSomething1(); //5 seconds.
var result2 = DoSomething2(); //5 seconds.
var result3 = DoSomething3(); //5 seconds.
var total = result1 + result2 + result3; // executes after 15 seconds.
```

Now if I make DoSomething() `async` and return a `Task<int>`

```
var result1 = DoSomething1(); 
var result2 = DoSomething2(); 
var result3 = DoSomething3(); 
int total = result1 + result2 + result3; // ERROR! result1,2,3 are Taxk<int> representing they are a handle to executing code.
```

Instead if we don't care about the results, and just do a `Console.WriteLine("Done");` You'll hit the total line nearly instantaneously because all you've effectively done is start 3x tasks. Each task will now take a bit longer than 5 seconds to run and return their result. For argument's sake, let's say 5.1 seconds. (it will be less than that, more like .01) This cost penalty is for the context switching. Your code "appears" to have run instantaneously because we've reached "Done" while worker threads are still executing our tasks. (Don't we care about the results? handling any exceptions?)

So, now we have 3x asyncronous methods available to run in parallel, we can use await to get the results:

var result1 = await DoSomething1(); 
var result2 = await DoSomething2(); 
var result3 = await DoSomething3(); 
int total = result1 + result2 + result3; // This now works.

However, how long do you think this takes to execute?  The answer will be 15.3 seconds. By using Await, each operation must wait for the other to complete.

"Well, what the heck is the point of this then?!" I'm sure some have asked. Well, to have these run in parallel, you can write it like so:

var result1 = DoSomething1(); 
var result2 = DoSomething2(); 
var result3 = DoSomething3(); 
int total = await result1 + await result2 + await result3; // This also works.

The execution time now? 5.1 seconds.

"AHA! so it is faster!" Yes, overall but only because it can, when it is safe to leverage a different thread for each operation AND the results of any code BEFORE the await is not dependent on anything from the previous async statements *and* deals with thread-safe references. There are other considerations like synchronization contexts, exception handling, and more. Keep in mind also that objects like EF's DbContext is *not* thread safe, so calling awaitable methods that each reference the same DbContext without awaiting them in sequence (because it should be faster in parallel) will lead to ugly little issues and errors.

This only covers the very basics of async/await. There is a lot more reading you should research from Microsoft and other sources about its use and limitations, and most importantly *when* to use it. It is NOT a silver bullet and should not be defaulted to whenever available because in most cases I've seen it used, it has lead to performance issues, and concurrency bugs with references to non-thread-safe code. It is intended for use where an operation can take a while to run, and you can safely finish off some code or kick off a parallel, independent operation before awaiting the result(s).  If your synchronous code has performance issues, 99.5% of the time these will *not* be solved by async/await. You're better off looking at exhausting possible explanations with the existing code before considering parallel operations. The main argument for async/await is making code more responsive.

Some materials to start with:

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/4240/your-ultimate-async-await-tutorial-in-c/introduction
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

I'm sure there will be other recommendations given for SO questions/answers and other resources.

On a final note: don't do this:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Throwing a new exception generates a new call stack. If you aren't doing anything to handle the exception, just remove the try/catch block. If you are doing something and want the exception to then bubble up, use `throw`:

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            VibrantTransaction.Rollback();
            AuditTransaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
```

This preserves the existing call stack for the exception.